# Best practice to convert multidimensional array to flat array of objects in ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have a source multidimensional array.
It looks like:

```
var arr = [];
arr[1] = [];
arr[2] = [];
arr[3] = [];
arr[1][1] = "11";
arr[1][2] = "12";
arr[1][3] = "13";
arr[2][1] = "21";
arr[2][2] = "22";
arr[2][3] = "23";
arr[3][1] = "31";
arr[3][2] = "32";
arr[3][3] = "33";
```

I need to convert this to a flat array using ES6 features.
Result must looks like this:

```
var res = [
  { col:1, row:1, val:"11"},
  { col:1, row:2, val:"12"},
  { col:1, row:3, val:"13"},
  { col:2, row:1, val:"21"},
  { col:2, row:2, val:"22"},
  { col:2, row:3, val:"23"},
  { col:3, row:1, val:"31"},
  { col:3, row:2, val:"32"},
  { col:3, row:3, val:"33"}
];
```

Comment: why starting indexes are 1?

Comment: the second piece of code, isn't a valid js, if you meant [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) you should replace `=` with `:`

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for new objects.

```js
var arr = [, [, '11', '12', '13'], [, '21', '22', '23'], [, '31', '32', '33']],
    result = arr.reduce((r, a, col) => (a.forEach((val, row) => r.push({ col, row, val })), r), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```